# PHP Time Zone Adjustment

Tags: php, timezone, date

I have a time that is being sent to me in UTC time, but I want to adjust it so its the outer edges of the days on East Coast time (EST/EDT). That is, I want the user to be able to enter in EDT/EST centric dates, and have it query with the UTC correct dates.

`$start_date` and `$end_date` are MM/DD/YYYY formatted dates passed via a GET variable.

```
 $start_date = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $start_date);
 $end_date = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', $end_date);
```

These dates are for use in a database query, whose times are stored in UTC time.

So, I want the start date to be the day before at 8pm or 7pm, depending on daylight savings, and then to end at 7:59:59 or 6:59:59, again depending on daylight savings.

How would I do that?

Comment: Which database are you using? Postgres for example has a field type called "timestamp with time zone" that does exactly what you're looking for. The database would take care of all your timezone conversions.

Comment: Have you checked [date_default_timezone_set()](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function ?

Answer (score 2):

If you know what timezone the data is coming from, you can do something like this:

```
$userTimezone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$systemTimezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');

$ts = new DateTime($datetime, $userTimezone);
$ts->setTimezone($systemTimezone);

return $ts->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Where $datetime is a valid date format according to thse rules - http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

This is the core of what we do in web2project - http://web2project.net/ - to get a datetime in the users' selected timezone but store it in GMT/UTC.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE date = DATE_SUB('2010-06-17 00:00:00',INTERVAL 4 HOUR);
```